# searching a value in a map using iterators

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program in which i declared two values , book name and isbn number,i am inserting these values in a map , with key value as their isbn number,in that i am searching for isbn number **1111111**(7 times 1), but while searching it it never becomes true,that means **flag** is not becoming **1**.
I tried debugging,while that i printed map,it was printing fine,but finally output for me is **Datastructures book is not available**,even though while printing map it showed the record of **Datastructures 1111111**. Here is the sample input and output

> **Sample input**
>
> OOPswithc++
>
> 1112523
>
> DatabaseManagementsystems
>
> 1558652
>
> ComputerArchitecture
>
> 1226355
>
> Compilerdesign
>
> 1225652
>
> Theory of computation
>
> 1311124
>
> JavaProgramming
>
> 1255555
>
> CProgramming
>
> 1555658
>
> Cloudcomputing
>
> 1322664
>
> Wirelessnetworks
>
> 1765565
>
> Datastructures
>
> 1111111
>
> **Sample output**
>
> Datastructures book is available

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string name;
    int isbn,flag=0;
    map<int,string> mymap;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
      getline(cin,name);
      cin.ignore();
      cin>>isbn;
      cin.ignore();
      mymap.insert(pair<int,string>(isbn,name)); 
    }
    map<int,string>::iterator itr=mymap.begin();
    for(itr=mymap.begin();itr!=mymap.end();++itr) {
      if((itr->first)==1111111) {
        flag=1;
        break;
      }
    }
   if(flag==1)
     cout<<"Datastructures book is available";
   else
     cout<<"Datastructures book is not available";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your question or problem you are facing?

Comment: for me output is **datastructure book is not available**,but as per input in question it should be **datastructure book is available**

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the map to see if they're what you think they are?

Comment: @Shawn,i am just searching the value with the help of key value,is it wrong?

Comment: I'd say how you're looking up an element is wrong because you're not using `.find()`, turning an **O(log N)** operation into an **O(N)** scan. But you're also not doing any error checking when reading input, and for debugging issues printing out the contents of your map might be enlightening. At the very least it rules out lots of potential causes.

Comment: i used **itr=mymap.find(1111111);** and i am still getting same output, i printed map too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first

```
 cin.ignore();
```

is consumuing the first "1" you input just make it like this and it should work

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        getline(cin, name);
        cin >> isbn;
        cin.ignore();
        mymap.insert(pair<int, string>(isbn, name));
    }
```